# Delphi: How to restore a form's original location when monitor configuration changes?

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a multi-form application in which a child form is positioned on the second monitor on startup, at which time its BoundsRect is saved.

When the computer's display configuration changes, Windows moves the form to the first (primary) monitor. I can catch this change with WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:

```
procedure WMDisplayChange(var msg: TWMDisplayChange); message WM_DISPLAYCHANGE;
```

What I'm interested in doing is moving the child form *back* to the second monitor when it reappears in the configuration (i.e. Screen.MonitorCount goes from 1 to 2), e.g.:

```
childForm.BoundsRect := childForm.m_WorkingBounds;
// (or)
childForm.BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[Screen.MonitorCount-1].BoundsRect;
```

However this assignment is have no affect -- the child form stays on monitor 0.

I've tried other approaches, such as SetWindowPos(), with no success ...

Comment: Seems pretty implausible to me that assigning to `BoundsRect` somehow does not work. I think we know that works correctly. Obviously replacing that call with `SetWindowPos` won't do any different since how do you think assignment to `BoundsRect` is implemented if not by a call to `SetWindowPos`. So the likely explanation is that the rhs of the assignment is not what you expect. Did you actually check that the value of `Screen.Monitors[Screen.MonitorCount-1].BoundsRect` matched your expectation? Have you done any debugging in other words?

Comment: If not for a very particular specific usage, this is not sound. A different monitor may appear at a different location.

Comment: @David: Yes I looked at those values in the debugger. All were as expected.

Comment: @Sertac: This is for a very particular and specific use case. The most common cause of the situation I'm trying to handle is using a high definition television via HDMI as the second monitor. Many models, when powered off, become invisible to Windows, causing the display configuration change. When the monitor is powered back on, I need to restore the configuration without having to restart the application.

Comment: So you are saying that you can assign to BoundsRect and the form does not respond. Can you tell us at what point in your code you do this. Can we reproduce this.

Comment: I'm doing this in the WMDisplayChange() handler. And I just noticed something rather odd: After I restore the second monitor, if I click on the child form while it is partially hidden behind the main form, it relocates to the correct position on the second monitor. So it seems that setting BoundsRect is having some of the desired results. Unfortunately I need to accomplish this without user interaction :|

Comment: I'll work on an MCVE.

Comment: @David Heffernan The good news is my MCVE works as I want it to. Unfortunately my target application does not. I've looked at various properties on the forms like border style, icons, double buffering, scaling, etc to see if any of those were a factor, but the MCVE always works. What's really odd about my target application is that according to what I see in the debugger, everything goes exactly as expected -- the child form's BoundsRect is set with the correct values -- the form itself just does not respond until some other external stimulus (like clicking on it) causes it to relocate.

Comment: Also ... bit of a newb question here ... I'm looking around for a way to upload my MCVE but I don't see anything. Are privileges required?

Comment: You add code to the question. That's why it needs to be minimal.

Comment: 4 votes for a non-existent problem. Yeah...

Answer (score 5):

Root of your problem is in the fact that Delphi VCL does not refresh its internal list of monitors when they actually change. You have to force that refresh yourself.

Monitors are refreshed with `TScreen.GetMonitors` method that is unfortunately private method so you cannot call it directly.

However, `TApplication.WndProc(var Message: TMessage)` processes `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` and upon receiving that message it calls Screen.GetMonitors - this is most benign way to achieve your goal.

When you receive notifications that monitors are changed just send it to Application:

```
SendMessage(Application.Handle, WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Related QC entry [Declare TScreen.GetMonitors public](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88635)

Comment: I think if it were me I'd just give up on the VCL properties and roll my own.

Comment: One would expect this shouldn't cause the issue in the question as the monitor seems to be detached and attached after the program is ran. We'd know if there was a mcve...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz OP is processing WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, so he is doing re-positioning while application is running. I am not saying he might not have other issues in his code. But this one is first in line he should take care of.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with old version Delphi5 and it worked easy just to:

```
Screen.Free;
Screen := TScreen.Create(Nil);
```

The screen handling has changed in later versions of Delphi, however a similar approach may work.